# OData service Out of memory exception

Tags: c#, odata

I have an OData service build under Web Api V2. I have a controller with a Linq query to return the data from a table. This is the controller query:

```
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<ImportContracts_ImportContracts> Get()
    {
        IQueryable<ImportContracts_ImportContracts> query = new List<ImportContracts_ImportContracts>().AsQueryable();

        query = (from BRRIMPORTCONTRACTS imcon in db.BRRIMPORTCONTRACTS.Where(x => x.ZZSTATE == 0)
                 select new
                 {
                     ReferenceDateData = imcon.ReferenceDate,
                     ImportationDate = imcon.ImportationDate,
                     LastImportation = imcon.LastImportation
                 }).ToList().Select(x => new ImportContracts_ImportContracts
                 {
                     ReferenceDateData = x.ReferenceDateData,
                     ImportationDate = x.ImportationDate,
                     LastImportation = x.LastImportation
                 }).AsQueryable();
        return query;
    }
```

My table BRRMIMPORTCONTRACTS have 1million records. When I get here, I get an System.OutOfMemoryException.

I know maybe this isn't the best way to query the entity but I just want a workaround for this.

I've tried [EnableQuery(PageSize=10)] hint but with no success. I think the problem is in the query itself.

Thanks in advance.
Filipe

Comment: Do a million records have the ZZState of 0?

Comment: You are loading everything in memory with `ToList()`, only to expose them as a Queryable that may only need a few of them. Don't do that. Why are you doing *two* selects instead of just one to return `ImportContracts_ImportContracts`?

Comment: Yes... 1million for ZZSTATE=0. ImportContracts_ImportContracts is class of a complex type. Is not a db table.

Comment: Don't do that then. EF entities don't have to map tables one-to-one. You can create an EF class named `ImportContracts_ImportContracts` that maps to a table with the fields you want.

Answer (score 0):

Does this make a difference?

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<ImportContracts_ImportContracts> Get()
{
    IQueryable<ImportContracts_ImportContracts> query = new List<ImportContracts_ImportContracts>().AsQueryable();

     query = (from BRRIMPORTCONTRACTS imcon in db.BRRIMPORTCONTRACTS.Where(x => x.ZZSTATE == 0)
         .Select(x => new ImportContracts_ImportContracts
         {
             ReferenceDateData = x.ReferenceDate,
             ImportationDate = x.ImportationDate,
             LastImportation = x.LastImportation
         });
    return query;
}
```

Note that your ToList() is gone, so an IQueryable is returned. Does that help?

Comment: I need the ToList(). Without that I get "The entity or complex type 'BRRODataServices.Models.ImportContracts_ImportContracts' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." error msg.

Comment: That isn't fixed by calling `ToList()`. `ToList()` loads everything in memory. If you want your entities to be named in a specific way, just name the classes the way you want them

Comment: You may be right. But the fact is that if I remove the ToList, or using just _one_ query I get the same error. I need this complex type as a class entity because i want to feed the OData with a kind of view but implemented in the controller.

Comment: That's why I in my solution I projected to an anonymous type and then to the IQueryable type. This works for a small set of data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you apply the query by yourself, for example

```
public IQueryable<ImportContracts_ImportContracts> Get(ODataQueryOptions<..> options)
{
    IQueryable<ImportContracts_ImportContracts> query = new List<ImportContracts_ImportContracts>().AsQueryable();

     // use the options to apply
     ...   

     return query;
}
```